# yesod devel error "cannot satisfy -package-key main"

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am new with `yesod` and have a strange problem.

I just do:

```
> stack new testProject yesod-mysql
> cd testProject
> yesod devel -v
```

And get this output:

> Yesod devel server. Type 'quit' to quit
>       ...
>       [10 of 10] Compiling Application      ( Application.hs, dist/build/Application.o )
>       Starting development server: runghc -package-dbdist/package.conf.inplace -package-idyesod-static-1.5.0.3-6NvTJROzmYNDUWjTfXoBEl -package-idyesod-form-1.4.7.1-Gzgnhxtpl1cHtZi8tpYJ6W -package-idyesod-core-1.4.20.2-LSkQJeMzDLa5Pa7kLbuyWE -package-idyesod-auth-1.4.13.2-BkxNkvnXCXHJK4Jcn5DCOG -package-idyesod-1.4.3-FozpcNynopR5dmIxJzx9wP -package-idyaml-0.8.17.1-IPQ39fXTYs6HOJXpZL5WSD -package-idwarp-3.2.6-EMPFQ0WMXK0LyTg9Lg5rBJ -package-idwai-logger-2.2.7-3YHWZq6HKajEjDJfMQEMPY -package-idwai-extra-3.0.15.1-FUnXXg3Vz52LuAJuCHPGaT -package-idwai-3.2.1-9pjoXeBvlCLGeOhAgcgOSZ -package-idvector-0.11.0.0-0444ed29a172c8c9f3affdad55a00e13 -package-idunordered-containers-0.2.7.0-eb2531a91f87979d5a2e9de1b078f8a1
>   -package-idtime-1.5.0.1-edbd1a50e7922b396ada189ab8e8523b -package-idtext-1.2.2.1-bd90209501b908bc79e4032fc38e47f7 -package-idtemplate-haskell-2.10.0.0-3c4cb52230f347282af9b2817f013181 -package-idshakespeare-2.0.8.2-Let4Je93qneC1Nfl494qaM -package-idsafe-0.3.9-e3aa437cf6afe091d2ac3ab91bc10ddd -package-idpersistent-template-2.1.6-EUymMpKPmxE54ia896mF3s -package-idpersistent-mysql-2.3.0.2-HpU8wMgRXTXGiRFshdlWNX -package-idpersistent-2.2.4.1-K0SUUK1ZVk4JJtT76N8FVA -package-idmysql-0.1.1.8-3047da6de17d2eaf02fcc6ae68d7ce79 -package-idmonad-logger-0.3.18-JIh1o7RvrrHLGPDtRuSVy8 -package-idmonad-control-1.0.1.0-22a9e4b9739808e702fc8251a1dc4535 -package-idhttp-conduit-2.1.10.1-DDGpLGxxWzO4lHgtxRUkKf -package-idhjsmin-0.2.0.1-JhGg7bhrA0D548DHQrOeec -package-idfile-embed-0.0.10-LIO3D2loTjuJO9Lps8PxJ7 -package-idfast-logger-2.4.6-2JY77Xt5kMm2HfluQ1ke36 -package-iddirectory-1.2.2.0-f8e14a9d121b76a00a0f669ee724a732 -package-iddata-default-0.5.3-a34fab0e414a3e31b9dccb1774520fca -package-idcontainers-0.5.6.2-e59c9b78d840fa743d4169d4bea15592 -package-idconduit-1.2.6.6-6VAuHz9CRA0HmWEsAB1s4R -package-idclassy-prelude-yesod-0.12.7-Aj4RVwagw6VEzBmKSFAy2b -package-idclassy-prelude-conduit-0.12.7-FT79eygBPV3CuOI3ecyxRd -package-idclassy-prelude-0.12.7-3FnNABKFDLNAOC5FwFI1yk -package-idcase-insensitive-1.2.0.6-5bc0eef1a20451ec195ee1b54e28c2d9 -package-idbytestring-0.10.6.0-c60f4c543b22c7f7293a06ae48820437 -package-idbase-4.8.2.0-0d6d1084fbc041e1cded9228e80e264d -package-idaeson-0.11.2.0-3W4IHFv12VV9EikLopLM1H -package-keymain app/devel.hs
>       : cannot satisfy -package-key main
>           (use -v for more information)
>       Exit code: ExitFailure 1

The stack build generates a valid binary. I use `gentoo` and have all `haskell` packages installed by emerge. I tried to start with `"stack build && stack exec -- yesod devel"`, but got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Gentoo have cabal version 1.24. Yesod devel successfully started after downgrade to 1.22.8